# Premature end of data while reading from WebResponse class

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, webrequest

I am developing a Windows Store App using C# and I am very new at this platform (I have been primarily working on IOS and Android).

I have a simple Async method to download raw data from a remote server. It works ok except that I keep seeing random incomplete reads from the WebResponse class. It is pretty simple method and I cant figure out why it would end prematurely. The remote server is working fine ( ios/web/android fine and are retrieving data) so I am obviously doing something wrong here.

Any help will be great in figuring out this problem.

```
public async Task<byte[]> doGETRequestAsync(String url)
{
    callSuccess = false;

    byte[] responseFromServer = null;
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);    
        request.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            responseFromServer = new byte[response.ContentLength];
            int readCount = await dataStream.ReadAsync(responseFromServer, 0, (int)response.ContentLength);
            if (readCount != response.ContentLength)
                throw new IOException("Premature end of data. Expected: " + response.ContentLength + " received: " + readCount);
        }


        response.Dispose();

    }
    catch (HttpRequestException hre)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception performing network call : " + hre.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception performing network call : " + e.ToString());
    }

    return responseFromServer;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The reason I added window store app in title was Tags are not pulled when google searching and This particular class name is too common and  makes searching very hard

Comment: That turns out not to be the case. Tags are very definitely used during searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using HttpClient and HttpClientHandler and it works perfectly. This also supports storing cookies and reusing that on every call.

Here is the code that can handle both GET and POST and return the data as an array of bytes[]. If the response is a utf8 encoded string, then the bytes can be converted to string using System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(respBytes, 0, respBytes.Length);

Hope it is helpful

```
class Network
{
   static CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
   List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postParameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

   // Add post parameter before calling NetworkRequestAsync for POST calls.
   public void addPostParameter(String key, String value)
   {
       postParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));

    }

    public async Task<byte[]> NetworkRequestAsync(String url, bool GET_REQUEST)
    {
        callSuccess = false;
        byte[] respBytes = null;
        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                // Use and reuse cookies in the cookiejar 
                CookieContainer = cookieJar
            };

            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            handler.UseCookies = true;

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpMessageHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(@url)
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            if (GET_REQUEST)
            {
                response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
            }
            else
            {

                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postParameters);
                //String postparam=await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //Debug.WriteLine("Post Param1=" + postparam);

                response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);

                callSuccess = true;
            }

            respBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception performing network call : " + e.ToString());
        } 

        return respBytes;
    }
```

}